# Inorganic question regarding Phosphorus-32

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

[image]

I am learning Inorganic Chemistry recently, and doing some pass year paper, and found this question. i am not sure how to identify  A3+.
Pls Help for question 1 ,2 ,& 3

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Optionally, to improve the question, read [formatting math/chemistry expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: For question ii, phosphorus-32 has the same electronic configuration as the usual phosphorus atom which is phosphorus-31.

Comment: Noted, will improve for the next question

Answer (score 1):

Isoelectronic means it has the same electronic structure and number of electrons, for example a negatively charged hydrogen ion (hydride) is isoelectronic with a helium atom.

Now phosphorus forms a simple 3- ion which appears in solids such as aluminium phosphide, the phosphide anion is isoelectronic with an argon atom. If we count three atomic numbers forwards from argon we go

Argon, Potassium, Calcium, Scandium. So A is scandium. If we remove three electrons from a scandium atom then we end up with a trication which is isoelectronic with argon.

Comment: Thx for that explanation, i really appreciate !